# Mongoose return count of all documents that match query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

All,

Question, I've got a query, that filters posts based on several criteria and then returns those posts. I then set a limit, skip (for pagination) and return them to the user.

What I'm trying to do now is implement pagination, what I need is to find count of total documents that match above query.

Basically, if I have, 100+ documents lets say in db that match query, but only returning 25. I need total count that match query.

Here is my query, I read about aggregate but not sure 100% how to implement it, or find a better solution to return total count of documents that match my query:

```
let regex = new RegExp(value.searchQuery, "i");
    const query = Post.find();
    if (value.searchQuery && value.city && value.category) {
        query.where({
            $and: [
                {
                    $or: [{ title: regex }, { description: regex }]
                }
            ],
            city: value.city,
            category: value.category
        });
    } else if (value.searchQuery && value.city && !value.category) {
        query.where({
            $and: [
                {
                    $or: [{ title: regex }, { description: regex }]
                }
            ],
            city: value.city
        });
    } else if (value.searchQuery && value.category && !value.city) {
        query.where({
            $and: [
                {
                    $or: [{ title: regex }, { description: regex }]
                }
            ],
            category: value.category
        });
    } else if (value.searchQuery && !value.city && !value.category) {
        query.where({
            $and: [
                {
                    $or: [{ title: regex }, { description: regex }]
                }
            ]
        });
    } else if (!value.searchQuery && value.city && value.category) {
        query.where({ city: value.city, category: value.category });
    } else if (!value.searchQuery && value.city && !value.category) {
        query.where({ city: value.city });
    } else if (!value.searchQuery && value.category && !value.city) {
        query.where({ category: value.category });
    }

    if (value.sort.createdAt) {
        query.setOptions({ createdAt: value.sort.createdAt });
    } else if (value.sort.deadline) {
        query.setOptions({ deadline: value.sort.deadline });
    }
    query
        .setOptions({
            limit: limitPerPage,
            skip: skipAmount,
            sort: !value.sort.createdAt
                ? { deadline: value.sort.deadline }
                : { createdAt: value.sort.createdAt }
        })
        .exec();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to perform second operation to get the count using `query.countDocuments()`

[Mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-countDocuments)

Comment: count() is deprecated right? countDocuments() is the one to use. But how would you perform this? I mean how should I pass all filters e.g contained in query.where(...)

Comment: You can add new variable `countQuery` like so

`const query = Post.find();
const countQuery = query;
if (value.searchQuery && value.city && value.category) {
        query.where({
            . . .
        });
countQuery.where({
            . . .
        }).count();
    }`
That should give you the count.